# MembershipCreateUserException when using Google OAuth in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth

I'm having problems getting Google OAuth to work with the default MVC4 Internet Application project template in Visual Studio 2012.

After redirection to Google and subsequently registering a username I'm getting a **MembershipCreateUserException** thrown on line 276 in the AccountController with the message:

> The username supplied is invalid.

The failing line of code is:

```
OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount(provider, providerUserId, model.UserName);
```

I've checked the database and the UserProfiles table contains the username I enter as expected and I've tried with various combinations of username.

Have I missed something as none of the linked articles within the source code suggest anything else needs configuring?

Comment: I have the same issue in my webapp (created from scratch). Did you manage to find a solution yet? Pretty much stuck on this point. The strange thing is, it DID work a few days ago...

Comment: @Dazl Lewis check my answer

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. The OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount needs to have a user in the Users table.

The thing is, the method will "create" a new record in the `webpages_OAuthMembership` table, which has a foreign key to the users table.

Thus, in order to make your call work either create a new user first via WebSecurity.CreateAccount or write some manual code to add a user to the table.

I went for the WebSecurity.CreateAccount and used the GeneratePassword method to work around that bit.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

First i would like to leave my experience here. (asp.net mvc4)

1. Change the dbcontext for the SimpleMembership provider. Go for Filter folder-> Open InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute. then do changes like this. So it will includ membership  tables in your database.

   ```
   WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("ChangeYourDbContext", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
   ```
2. Go for AccontController. Find the UserContext, which is by default using the defaultConnection string.   Go for UserContext Declartion (<kbd>f12</kbd>). 
   and override the UserContext Connectionstring to your actualDbcontext

   ```
   public UsersContext(): base("YourAcutalDbContext")
   {

   }
   ```